# Looking for local onboarding glossary

Tags: discussion, new-users

Disclaimer: Posted using an alternate account as I want to manage my new questions about community building and other topics separate from my old account.

Besides using this account to ask about Community Building I will use it to follow topics across the network like Google Drive that are cross-plaftorm (apps for the Web, Windows, MacOS, Android, iPhone and iPad) and multiple roles end-user, programming, webmaster, system administrators, etc.

---

Does this community have a **glossary** for new members or complementary resources to the site Tour and Help Center? Is there a preferred external reference for vocabulary about *community building*? Do you think that Wikipedia is a good encyclopedic reference?

I searched this meta site using the following keywords: `glossary`, `terminology`, and `vocabulary`. I look at [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) and [new-users](/questions/tagged/new-users).

I found the following local posts:

- [How to deal with SE-centric answers?](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30/7020)
  The top answer to this meta question proposes actions to attract users that are biased by the Stack Exchange paradigm. The other answers are similar. In general, this question and its answers don't suggest specific actions and don't include pointers to what I'm asking.
- [Proposal for community curated resource questions](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1299/7020)
  This meta question is not asking for a glossary for new users of this community. The answer points to [Authoritative reference works on best practices in online community building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/1039/7020) which partially answers this question as its answers point to several external resources. The problem is that the question is from 2015 and the newest answer is from 2016. It would be nice to get current opinions about those resources or if there is something newer. As I have not enough rep I can't offer a bounty. I would not like to use the association bonus of my old account as that might block this account from participating while the bounty is active in order to avoid "abuse" the system

I assume that the answer is no. Please confirm and provide an opinion about how new users, like me and users that are completely new to Stack Exchange and community building, can help themselves to understand the common vocabulary and use the proper terms.

If someone feels generous (in terms of willing "donate" some reputation) please consider offering a bounty in [Proposal for community curated resource questions](https://communitybuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1299/7020) or another old related question to attract attention, i.e. offering the bounty to recognize an existing great answer, one that you is already considered a canonical answer or to attracted new answers to add up to date content, I will be deeply grateful.

#### Markdown / HTML

Stack Exchange supports the HTML tags for definition lists. This might worth to be mentioned in a guidance / [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) post. Example:

```
<dl>
<dt>Word 1</dt><dd>Definition 1</dd>
<dt>Word 2</dt><dd>Definition 2</dd>
<dt>Word 3</dt><dd>Definition 3</dd>
</dl>
```

Word 1

Definition 1

Word 2

Definition 2

Word 3

Definition 3

## Related

- [Our words are too complicated. Let's make them simpler!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/269289/1359324)
- [Stack Exchange Glossary - Dictionary of Commonly-Used Terms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/40353/1359324)
- [Is it possible to have definition lists in Markdown?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72395/1359324)
- [Why aren't description lists formatted on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346405/1359324)

## Note to self

I could post this without including a link to a post on the main site because I have rep 11 at the time of posting (the required rep is +5).

---

## Progress updates

### Main-Site Tags

[communit-standards](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communit-standards), [rules-and-policies](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rules-and-policies), [new-members](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/new-members), [user-engagement](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user-engagement), [site-culture](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-culture)

### Main-Site Related Posts

Oldest post first.

- [What are techniques that encourage new members to familiarize themselves with community guidelines?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/440/7020)
- [How do you onboard new community members?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2872/7020)
- [How did you successfully introduce Slack and on-board your community?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/q/2875/7020)